# Is it possible to use a serializable data class as post request body in ktorfit

Tags: kotlin, serialization, jvm

In **Ktorfit** documentation the @Body parameter is presented as a `String`. When I tried to define it as a data class it threw a serialization error. Below is an example of how I'm trying to define the endpoint

```
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
@POST("login")
suspend fun login(@Body user: UserDto): String
```

**Data class definition**

```
@Serializable
data class UserDto(
    @SerialName("User") val userLogin: UserLogin
)

@Serializable
data class UserLogin(
    @SerialName("login_id") val loginId: String,
    val password: String
)
```

**Error:**

```
Exception in thread "main" kotlinx.serialization.SerializationException: Serializer for class 'Any' is not found.
Mark the class as @Serializable or provide the serializer explicitly.
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it, but you probably have to setup content negotiation in your Ktor client so it handles serialization/deserialization:
https://ktor.io/docs/serialization-client.html#register_json

```kotlin
val myClient = HttpClient(CIO) {
    install(ContentNegotiation) {
        json()
    }
}
```

This requires a dependency on `ktor-serialization-kotlinx-json`.

Then use this custom Ktor client in Ktorfit's config:

```kotlin
val ktorfit = Ktorfit.Builder().httpClient(myClient).build()
```

Comment: Joffrey, I have that already setup. The response is deserialized as expected, the issue is with request body.

Comment: You might also need a specific `contentType(ContentType.Application.Json)` as far as Ktor is concerned. In that case, I'm not sure how to make Ktorfit set it. You could of course use Ktorfit's `@Header` in your method, and then create an extension function that prefills it with `application/json`, but that seems like a lot of boilerplate. There might be a way to set a default for this in Ktor itself, for instance using the [default request](https://ktor.io/docs/default-request.html) plugin